# Compare rows in a matrix and count the number of equal elements

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to compare rows in a matrix and count the number of equal elements in the rows. Say I have a matrix:

```
[['food', 'food', 'food'],
 ['food', 'food', 'drink'],
 ['food', 'food', 'drink']]
```

I would like to compare the first row with the second row, the first row with the third row, and the second row with the third row. There is no need to compare two rows two times and I don't want to compare a row with itself. I'd like to return a list or array that is as long as the number of comparisons (or similar) and that contains the number of equal elements for each comparison. In this case, I'd get: [2, 2, 3].

I've tried looping through the matrix as follows:

```
comparisons = [sum(matrix[i]==matrix[j]) for i in range(len(matrix)) for j in range(len(matrix)) if i < j]
```

I'm worried this solution will be too slow if the size of the matrix grows. Is there a more efficient solution by using e.g. NumPy?

Comment: ```sum(matrix[i]==matrix[j])``` aren't you trying to sum a boolean here?

Comment: Not sure but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(
         (matrix[i+1:] == row).sum(1) for i, row in enumerate(matrix[:-1])
        ))
[2, 2, 3]
```

Timing:

```
# Method 1 [from the question]
>>> %timeit [sum(matrix[i]==matrix[j]) for i in range(len(matrix)) for j in range(len(matrix)) if i < j]
25.6 µs ± 1.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# Method 2
>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable((matrix[i+1:] == row).sum(1) for i, row in enumerate(matrix[:-1])))
11.8 µs ± 320 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```